# How do I insert many documents (100 millions) to a local mongodb with multiprocessing?

Tags: json, python-3.x, mongodb, multiprocessing, pymongo

I successfully inserted many JSON files (only chosen keys) to a local MongoDB. However, when a collection has a little bit more than 100 million rows that need to be inserted my code seems so slow. I hope multiprocessing will help speeds up the process but I can't come up with the correct ways of doing it without any conflict. Here is my code without multiprocessing:

```
import json
import os

from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client[db_name]


# get file list
def log_list(log_folder):
    log_file = list()
    for entry in os.listdir(log_folder):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(log_folder, entry)):
            log_path = os.path.join(log_folder, entry)
            log_file.append(log_path)
    return log_file


def func():
    collection = db[collection_name]
    print('loading folder_name')
    root = folder_path
    nfile = 0
    nrow = 0
    # insert data
    files = log_list(root)
    files.sort()
    for file in files:
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            nfile += 1
            table = [json.loads(line) for line in f]
        for row in table:
            nrow += 1
            entry = {'timestamp': row['@timestamp'], 'user_id': row['user']['id'], 'action': row['@type']}
            collection.insert_one(entry).inserted_id
    client.close()
    print(nfile, 'file(s) processed.', nrow, 'row(s) loaded.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this in our project, users upload lot of files for some task, we handle it using distributed task queues using Celery.

Since this is a similar, asynchronous task,  'Celery' can do great here, it is designed to pick up tasks and then execute in separate process.

1. Create a task
2. Set up a broker (like redis)
3. Run celery in another terminal or in the background
4. send the task (see task_name.apply_async() or task_name.delay() )

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Split your file into several files. Run a single copy of your program for each chunk of the file. When writing to the database use [`insert_many`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many) rather than `insert_one` to write more efficiently to the database.

You can use Python [multiprocessing](https://pymotw.com/2/multiprocessing/basics.html) to fork multiple parallel jobs.